# Resize and Convert all uploading image into png format

Tags: php

First I want to tell you guys I'm a beginner to this. I'm developing a website, I want to allow users to upload any size of images in a variety of formats (GIF,JPEG,PNG).
And I want to re size the image and convert the image format into PNG. Im not inserting the image into database as BLOBs.

this is my code, But I'm uploading the image directly here, How to re size and convert to PNG:

```
$myImage = $_FILES['imgCover']['name'];

$response = mysql_query("INSERT INTO gallery (imagename) VALUE ('$myImage')");
if($response  === true)
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imgCover']['tmp_name'],"images/gallery/".$_FILES['imgCover']['name'])
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Tell us how we can help you.. And we will

Comment: Appreciate. As I mention, I want to resize the image and convert it into 'PNG' format then upload.

Comment: If you're looking for somebody to write you an entire PHP script to carry that out, you've come to the wrong place. You get started and then come back when you have a **specific** problem within your code.

Comment: See if your server has GD or Image Magick loaded on it. This is a good place to start for programming with those libraries. http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2008/10/resize-images-using-phpgd-library.html?

Just use png where its says jpeg, like

```
imagejpeg
```

etc.